# Keil uVision - Atmel SAM3U Read Unique Identifier

Tags: arm, embedded, microcontroller, keil, atmel

I've been trying to read the Unique Identifier (UID) from a Atmel SAM3U MCU, but it's proven more difficult than it needs to be to make it happen. Does anyone have any examples or can suggest how to read it properly? Whenever I do, I wait in a `do while` loop (like the documentation states) for the EEFC (Flash ROM) status register to change states, but it never does so the MCU is then stuck in a loop.

[image: Atmel Read Unique Identifier Document]

Here is the code I'm using

```
// must run this from SRAM
__attribute__((section(".ARM.__at_0x20080000"))) void Get_Unique_ID(unsigned int *pdwUniqueID)
{
    Efc *p_efc;
    unsigned int status;
    
    // clear the array
    pdwUniqueID[0] = 0;
    pdwUniqueID[1] = 0;
    pdwUniqueID[2] = 0;
    pdwUniqueID[3] = 0;
    
    // send the Start Read Unique Identifier command (STUI) by writing the Flash Command Register with the STUI command
    p_efc->EEFC_FCR = EEFC_FCR_FKEY_PASSWD | EEFC_FCR_FCMD_STUI;
    
    // wait for the Flash Programming Status Register (EEFC_FSR) to fall
    do { status = p_efc->EEFC_FSR; }
    while ((status & EEFC_FSR_FRDY) == EEFC_FSR_FRDY);
    
    // the Unique Identifier is located in the first 128 bits of the Flash memory mapping
    pdwUniqueID[0] = *(unsigned int *)IFLASH0_ADDR;
    pdwUniqueID[1] = *(unsigned int *)(IFLASH0_ADDR + 4);
    pdwUniqueID[2] = *(unsigned int *)(IFLASH0_ADDR + 8);
    pdwUniqueID[3] = *(unsigned int *)(IFLASH0_ADDR + 12);
    
    // to stop the Unique Identifier mode, the user needs to send the Stop Read unique Identifier
    // command (SPUI) by writing the Flash Command Register with the SPUI command
    p_efc->EEFC_FCR = EEFC_FCR_FKEY_PASSWD | EEFC_FCR_FCMD_SPUI;
    
    // when the Stop Read Unique Unique Identifier command (SPUI) has been performed
    // the FRDY bit in the Flash Programming Status Register (EEFC_FSR) rises
    do { status = p_efc->EEFC_FSR; }
    while ((status & EEFC_FSR_FRDY) != EEFC_FSR_FRDY);
}
```

Note that `__attribute__((section(".ARM.__at_0x20080000")))` isn't the best method to dynamically assign this function to SRAM via the linker and any suggestions on how to make it more dynamic would be appreciated.

***SOLVED*** The problem was the chips I had were fake so SAM-BA was returning whatever was at the SRAM buffer address it specified. It's a bug in SAM-BA since if it received 0x00000000, it should give an error or warning message and then stop reading. *Do not buy fake chips from China!*

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason why you don't write the loops as for example `while((p_efc->EEFC_FSR & EEFC_FSR_FRDY)==0){}`?

Comment: Reason I ask is because the SAM parts tend to have mysterious undocumented side effects in a few registers. Sometimes you have to read the whole register without masking bitfields, or undocumented silicon mysteries will occur.

Comment: The loop code isn't the issue I don't think. The problem is the MCU isn't triggering those Flash ROM (EEFC) register bits hence why it's actually stuck in that loop.

Comment: Did you disable all interrupts ("IRQ disable") before calling the function?

Comment: Yes, the interrupts were disabled.

Comment: Just an update, `__attribute__((section(".ARM.__at_0x20080000")))` isn't the correct method in Keil. You need to right click on C file and change the options memory assignment to SRAM. Still however, the function locks up. However, if I change the `main()` function to also execute from SRAM which calls `Get_Unique_ID` then it does not lock up. With that done though, the UID is **still** incorrect. It does not match the one I get back from SAM-BA.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe `p_efc` is correctly initialized.
You create a pointer to a `Efc` datastructure which thus points to *something*.

You then write *something* to *somewhere* and are expect it to work.

```
Efc *p_efc;
p_efc->EEFC_FCR = EEFC_FCR_FKEY_PASSWD | EEFC_FCR_FCMD_STUI;
```

My guess would be that you need to intialize it to the correct EEFC base address. The [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-6430-32-bit-Cortex-M3-Microcontroller-SAM3U4-SAM3U2-SAM3U1_Datasheet.pdf#page=34) has the following to say:

> The SAM3U4 (256 Kbytes internal Flash
> version) embeds two EEFC (EEFC0 for Flash0 and EEFC1 for Flash1)
> whereas the SAM3U2/1 embeds one EEFC.

So depending on your MCU version you need to address EEFC0 or EEFC1. I'm assuming that you use libopencm3 but this will work for any other library. Look for the [EEFC location define](http://libopencm3.org/docs/latest/sam3u/html/eefc_8h.html#a60e7cc579baaf841738f01879c91bd34). Following the defines/files/links we get to [this page](http://libopencm3.org/docs/latest/sam3u/html/sam_23u_2memorymap_8h.html#a31d51dba3829d9a7b98059edac78b291), it tells us to point our `Efc` pointer to `EEFC0_BASE` or `EEFC1_BASE`. I would advise you to use the `EEFC0` and `EEFC1` defines though as it makes your code portabler.

So your code should work if your Efc is located in `EEFC0` if you do:

```
Efc *p_efc = EEFC0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have changed it all to ditch the pointer to the `Efc` datastructure and instead use `EEFC0`. Also, I have made both files (IE: MAIN.C and UID.C which contains the code example above) compile in the SRAM area. The code now works and does not freeze, but the values I'm getting back are completely different from SAM-BA. Any ideas why that's happening? I can upload my entire simple Keil example project if you'd like to check it out.

Comment: Also, I'm not using **libopencm3**. I am using the Keil uVision libraries and includes for the 3U1C. This variant of the ARM MCU only has one EEFC which is actually defined as EFC0. With my comment above, the pointer is now completely removed and as stated I am using the define directly (IE: `EFC0->EEFC_FCR = EEFC_FCR_FKEY_PASSWD | EEFC_FCR_FCMD_STUI;`). So to clarify, all references to `p_efc->` are now simply `EFC0->`. However, I'm not getting the right bits back. I get `0x44203120` for the first address using the code above where it should actually be `0x574A73F8` according to SAM-BA.